# Decrementing value stored in a queue

Tags: java, queue

I'm working on a queue project where the program is simulating a grocery store. In my program, I have a method call that sets up a random variable that represents the time that it takes to service the customer in queue.  The total iterations are 60, signifying minutes.  Say if the first customer is given a 4 minute wait time, I need to be able to decrement the time after each minute until it reaches 0.  I cannot figure out how to decrement the value stored in the queue named `myQueue`.  Any suggestions how I can decrease the value stored in the queue after each minute?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GroceryStore{
public static void main (String[] args){

int newCust=0;  //to hold random variable 1-4 for 25% chance of new customer
Queue<Integer> myQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>(); //instantiates new queue
int wait = 0;
int numCust = 0;                        //holds counter for number of  customer             

for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)  //iterator to cycle through 60 minutes
{

    Random randomNum = new Random();    
    newCust = randomNum.nextInt(4)+1;  //gives random #1-4, if 1, new cust added

    if(newCust == 1)                            //if statement to execute code if new cust added
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        wait = cust.getServiceTime();                                           //stores wait time in variable
        myQueue.add(wait);                                                      //adds customer to the queue by wait time
        System.out.println("New customer added to queue, queue length is now " + myQueue.size());                       
    }

    if(myQueue.isEmpty())                                       //if to check if queue is empty and skip other conditionals
        System.out.println("-----------");
    else if(myQueue.peek()==0)                                  //if top of queue is at 0, remove from queue
    {
        myQueue.remove();
        System.out.println("Customer removed");
    }
    else    
          //THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO DECREASE THE VALUE IN THE TOP QUEUE
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this implementation feels very complicated to me. It's very hard to follow (always a bad sign) but it seems like you want to keep track of how long each person was waiting in line. If that's the case, then you may want to add a "StartTime" property to your `Customer` class and then `cust.StartTime = i;` to keep track of when they got in line. When they're finished checking out, you can do a `int totalTimeWaited = i - curCust.StartTime;` to find out how long they were in line for.

Comment: Also, you could clean up the `Random` part a bit by just doing `if(Math.random() <= 0.25) { ... new Customer(); ... }`

Comment: Yeah, rather than decrement a time value, keep the the time when the customer should be "serviced" and do arithmetic on that value when you need to know if the wait time has expired.  You can even use a keyed queue, keyed on this time value, and have the customers be delivered in the order you need them.  You'd then only ever need to look at the first customer in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is immutable, so wrap an `int` in your own class:

```
class Customer {

    int time;

    public Customer(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    // getter, setter
}
```

and define a corresponding `Queue`:

```
Queue<Customer> myQueue = new ...;
```

Instantiate a `java.util.Timer`; in the corresponding `java.util.TimerTask`, iterate through the `Queue` using a *for-each* loop, altering or removing each in turn:

```
for (Customer c : myQueue) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wanting to decrement a value stored in the Customer object that is located at the top of the queue.

The easiest way would be to add a method to reduce the serviceTime within the Customer class.

```
public decServiceTime() {
  serviceTime--;
}
```

Looking at the value associated to the Customer object sitting in the queue you can perform the actions necessary.

Also if you have any questions you should first try sending me, your TA an email. =)

Comment: Haha. Sorry I'm used to having TA's that weren't really willing to help.  I ended up implementing a variable that kept track of the amount of time left in the top queue's object.  I then just decremented it based on certain conditions.  Thanks everyone for the suggestions!